# Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.geolocation

Tags: multi-device-hybrid-apps

I download this example

[WinJS ToDo Sample for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WinJS-TODO-Sample-for-17295485)

but when compile get the error:

> Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.geolocation

I remove the check "Geolocation" in config.xml and the error changes to:

> Failed to fetch package information for
>   com.msopentech.azure-mobile-services

How can I solve this problem?

thanks
regards

Comment: is very strange, remove "Geolocation" and "Mobile Service" check from config.xml, run the application with ripple emulator and geolocation resolves the position, how is it possible ? if I remove the plugin from config.xml

Comment: On build it needs to download those plugins from the Cordova plugin registry.  It seems like you might not have network connectivity or there is a firewall preventing the download.  The reason position is available in Ripple even without the geolocation plugin is because that plugin is just a light wrapper around the W3C Geolocation API and only executes on devices that don't already provide an implementation.  The machine you are running on already supports the geolocation API so things work even without the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your network connectivity and firewall settings.  The plugins need to be downloaded from the Cordova plugin registry and it looks like it's unable to do that on your system.

Comment: thanks, the problem was the internet connection, it block the plugin download